# OpenGL texture glTexCoord2d is not drawing

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I'm having problems render a opengl texture.

I'm trying to load a texture from a png image
The parser I'm using is from here https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/ahrs-visualizer/blob/master/png_texture.cpp

```
char str[]="bottom2.png";
GLuint image = png_texture_load(str,  NULL, NULL);
```

And is returning a GLuint 61964157, so seems to be working.

So, my program has a method that go through the obj and put the vertex in the array depending on the type and get a counter of the  size of the array

```
struct Vertice vertArrV[5000];
struct Vertice vertArrF[5000];
struct Vertice vertArrVT[5000];
struct Vertice vertArrVN[5000];
```

Then in my display mehod call all that opengl initializers, similar to also the same repo how the init things https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/ahrs-visualizer/blob/master/ahrs-visualizer.cpp#L339

Then in my display method, who is the one called by glutDisplayFunc

```
    void display() {  // Display function will draw the image.

    glewInit();

    glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 1 );  // (In fact, this is the default.)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear buffers
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    int i=1;
    char str[]="knight.png";
    GLuint image = png_texture_load(str,  NULL, NULL);

    if (image == 0 )
    {
        printf("\n error loading texture \n");
        return;
    }

    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();


for(i;i<arrayCount[2];i++){
    struct Vertice face =vertArrF[i];
    struct Vertice verticeLoop1 =vertArrV[face.vert1];
    struct Vertice verticeNormalLoop1 =vertArrVN[face.vertn1];
    struct Vertice verticeTextureLoop1 =vertArrVT[face.vertt1];
    struct Vertice verticeLoop2 =vertArrV[face.vert2];
    struct Vertice verticeNormalLoop2 =vertArrVN[face.vertn2];
    struct Vertice verticeTextureLoop2 =vertArrVT[face.vertt2];
    struct Vertice verticeLoop3 =vertArrV[face.vert3];
    struct Vertice verticeNormalLoop3 =vertArrVN[face.vertn3];
    struct Vertice verticeTextureLoop3 =vertArrVT[face.vertt3];


    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glNormal3d( verticeNormalLoop1.x,verticeNormalLoop1.y,verticeNormalLoop1.z);
    glTexCoord2d(verticeTextureLoop1.x, verticeTextureLoop1.y);
    glVertex3d( verticeLoop1.x,verticeLoop1.y,verticeLoop1.z);


    glNormal3d( verticeNormalLoop2.x,verticeNormalLoop2.y,verticeNormalLoop2.z);
    glTexCoord2d(verticeTextureLoop2.x, verticeTextureLoop2.y);
    glVertex3d( verticeLoop2.x,verticeLoop2.y,verticeLoop2.z);

    glNormal3d( verticeNormalLoop3.x,verticeNormalLoop3.y,verticeNormalLoop3.z);
    glTexCoord2d(verticeTextureLoop3.x, verticeTextureLoop3.y);
    glVertex3d( verticeLoop3.x,verticeLoop3.y,verticeLoop3.z);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GLenum err = glGetError();
    while (err != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        printf("%f %f %f\n ",verticeNormalLoop1.x,verticeNormalLoop1.y);
        printf("%f %f %f\n ",verticeNormalLoop2.x,verticeNormalLoop2.y);
        printf("%f %f %f\n ",verticeNormalLoop3.x,verticeNormalLoop3.y);
        printf("%f %f %f\n ",verticeLoop1.x,verticeLoop1.y);
        printf("%f %f %f\n ",verticeLoop2.x,verticeLoop2.y);
        printf("%f %f %f\n ",verticeLoop3.x,verticeNormalLoop3.y);
        printf("%f %f %f\n ",verticeTextureLoop1.x,verticeTextureLoop1.y);
        printf("%f %f %f\n ",verticeTextureLoop2.x,verticeTextureLoop2.y);
        printf("%f %f %f\n ",verticeTextureLoop3.x,verticeTextureLoop3.y);
        printf("error ");
        printf("%s\n %d \n",GetGLErrorString(err), i);
        err = glGetError();
    }

}

    glScalef(0.02,0.02,0.02);
    glRotatef(45,1,1,0);


    glutSwapBuffers(); // Required to copy color buffer onto the screen.

}
```

Also for debugging I put a printf on the texture vertex, and seems to be feeding the glTexCoord2d with the expected values

```
 0.863281 0.218750 0.0000000.863281 0.218750 0.0000000.863281 0.218750 0.0000000.863281 0.039062 0.0000000.863281 0.218750 0.0000000.992188 0.039062 0.0000000.730469 0.472656 0.0000000.992188 0.527344 0.0000000.875000 0.328125 0.0000000.753906 0.453125 0.0000000.875000 0.328125 0.0000000.871094 0.441406 0.0000000.863281 0.210938 0.0000000.753906 0.453125 0.0000000.753906 0.453125 0.0000000.730469 0.417969 0.0000000.730469 0.417969 0.0000000.863281 0.218750 0.0000000.863281 0.000000 0.0000000.992188 0.277344 0.0000000.992188 0.410156 0.0000000.960938 0.554688 0.0000000.871094 0.441406 0.0000000.992188 0.277344 0.0000000.992188 0.410156 0.0000000.992188 0.093750 0.0000000.992188 0.148438 0.0000000.730469 0.472656 0.0000000.871094 0.441406 0.0000000.992188 0.148438 0.0000000.992188 0.410156 0.0000000.753906 0.527344 0.0000000.753906 0.453125 0.0000000.871094 0.441406 0.0000000.753906 0.527344 0.0000000.871094 0.441406 0.0000000.992188 0.527344 0.0000000.992188 0.148438 0.0000000.960938 0.550781 0.0000000.964844 0.554688 0.0000000.164062 0.308594 0.0000000.371094 0.250000 0.0000000.382812 0.273438 0.0000000.371094 0.550781 0.0000000.218750 0.550781 0.0000000.371094 0.250000 0.0000000.382812 0.273438 0.0000000.164062 0.308594 0.0000000.960938 0.550781 0.0000000.371094 0.292969 0.0000000.382812 0.273438 0.0000000.960938 0.550781 0.0000000.960938 0.550781 0.0000000.960938 0.550781 0.0000000.960938 0.550781 0.0000000.164062 0.000000 0.0000000.175781 0.023438 0.0000000.164062 0.000000 0.0000000.175781 0.023438 0.0000000.355469 0.000000 0.0000000.355469 0.019531 0.0000000.410156 0.339844 0.0000000.175781 0.339844 0.0000000.355469 0.000000 0.0000000.355469 0.019531 0.0000000.246094 0.101562 0.0000000.246094 0.101562 0.0000000.355469 0.019531 0.0000000.378906 0.062500 0.0000000.210938 0.375000 0.0000000.382812 0.375000 0.0000000.355469 0.019531 0.0000000.378906 0.062500 0.0000000.003906 0.214844 0.0000000.003906 0.214844 0.0000000.386719 0.132812 0.0000000.378906 0.062500 0.0000000.210938 0.417969 0.0000000.386719 0.417969 0.0000000.386719 0.132812 0.0000000.378906 0.062500 0.0000000.191406 0.222656 0.0000000.191406 0.222656 0.0000000.347656 0.203125 0.0000000.386719 0.132812 0.0000000.218750 0.476562 0.0000000.378906 0.476562 0.0000000.347656 0.203125 0.0000000.386719 0.132812 0.0000000.164062 0.308594 0.0000000.164062 0.253906 0.0000000.347656 0.203125 0.0000000.371094 0.250000 0.0000000.222656 0.515625 0.0000000.375000 0.515625 0.0000000.347656 0.203125 0.0000000.371094 0.250000 0.0000000.003906 0.386719 0.0000000.371094 0.292969 0.0000000.382812 0.273438 0.0000000.003906 0.386719 0.0000000.371094 0.578125 0.0000000.218750 0.578125 0.0000000.003906 0.386719 0.0000000.003906 0.386719 0.0000000.003906 0.253906 0.0000000.003906 0.253906 0.0000000.003906 0.066406 0.0000000.003906 0.066406 0.0000000.363281 0.605469 0.0000000.226562 0.605469 0.0000000.164062 0.386719 0.0000000.320312 0.957031 0.0000000.265625 0.957031 0.0000000.226562 0.957031 0.0000000.226562 0.992188 0.0000000.410156 0.957031 0.0000000.386719 0.957031 0.0000000.386719 0.957031 0.0000000.386719 0.992188 0.0000000.363281 0.957031 0.0000000.320312 0.957031 0.0000000.960938 0.554688 0.0000000.964844 0.554688 0.0000000.960938 0.550781 0.0000000.015625 0.570312 0.0000000.082031 0.570312 0.0000000.363281 0.871094 0.0000000.328125 0.871094 0.0000000.257812 0.871094 0.0000000.328125 0.871094 0.0000000.226562 0.871094 0.0000000.226562 0.933594 0.0000000.460938 0.957031 0.0000000.437500 0.957031 0.0000000.437500 0.957031 0.0000000.437500 0.992188 0.0000000.449219 0.914062 0.0000000.386719 0.957031 0.0000000.386719 0.933594 0.0000000.410156 0.933594 0.0000000.386719 0.933594 0.0000000.074219 0.527344 0.0000000.226562 0.933594 0.0000000.226562 0.957031 0.0000000.328125 0.933594 0.0000000.257812 0.933594 0.0000000.363281 0.933594 0.0000000.328125 0.933594 0.0000000.460938 0.957031 0.0000000.480469 0.957031 0.0000000.265625 0.832031 0.0000000.265625 0.832031 0.0000000.328125 0.871094 0.0000000.449219 0.914062 0.0000000.449219 0.914062 0.0000000.015625 0.570312 0.0000000.320312 0.832031 0.0000000.156250 0.515625 0.0000000.167969 0.484375 0.0000000.210938 0.511719 0.0000000.128906 0.515625 0.0000000.960938 0.550781 0.0000000.964844 0.554688 0.0000000.109375 0.484375 0.0000000.121094 0.585938 0.0000000.128906 0.515625 0.0000000.148438 0.457031 0.0000000.148438 0.457031 0.0000000.156250 0.414062 0.0000000.156250 0.515625 0.0000000.156250 0.414062
```

[image: Result when running]

OpenGL Call Stack

```
1: CGLChoosePixelFormat({kCGLPFAAllowOfflineRenderers}, 0x7fa96fd10c10, 2);
2: CGLCreateContext(0x7fa96fd10c10, 0x00000000, 0x7fa971007600);
3: glDrawBuffer(GL_FRONT);
4: glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
5: CGLSetParameter(0x7fa971007600, kCGLCPSwapInterval, {1});
6: CGLSetSurface(0x7fa971007600, {100, 78, 500, 522}, {0, 22, 500, 500});
7: glScissor(0, 0, 500, 500);
8: glViewport(0, 0, 500, 500);
9: CGLQueryRendererInfo(4294967295, 0x00000000, -1059176193);
10: CGLDestroyRendererInfo(0x7fa96fd46710);
11: glViewport(0, 0, 500, 500);
12: glGetString(GL_VERSION);
13: glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS);
14: glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
15: glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
16: glEnable(GL_BLEND);
17: glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
18: glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
19: glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
20: glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
21: glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
22: glGenTextures(1, 0x7fff59a00a08);
23: glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 152813080);
24: glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0x10b856000);
25: glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
26: glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
27: glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
28: glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
29: glLoadIdentity();
30: glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
31: glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
32: glNormal3d(0.525731, 0.850651, 0);
33: glTexCoord2d(0.730469, 0.257812);
34: glVertex3d(3.48344, -1.48562, 24.4911);
35: glNormal3d(-0.525731, 0.850651, 0);
36: glTexCoord2d(0.992188, 0.277344);
37: glVertex3d(3.73332, -1.23742, 20.78);
38: glNormal3d(0.262866, -0.951056, -0.16246);
39: glTexCoord2d(0.875, 0.328125);
40: glVertex3d(4.60787, -3.71942, 22.2232);
41: glEnd();
42: glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
43: glGetError(); returns: GL_INVALID_OPERATION 
44: glGetError(); returns: GL_NO_ERROR 
45: glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
46: glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
47: glNormal3d(0.525731, 0.850651, 0);
48: glTexCoord2d(0.730469, 0.257812);
49: glVertex3d(3.48344, -1.48562, 24.4911);
50: glNormal3d(-0.587785, 0.425325, 0.688191);
51: glTexCoord2d(0.863281, 0.039062);
52: glVertex3d(-1.76387, -0.741022, 22.2232);
53: glNormal3d(-0.525731, 0.850651, 0);
54: glTexCoord2d(0.992188, 0.277344);
55: glVertex3d(3.73332, -1.23742, 20.78);
56: glEnd();
57: glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
58: glGetError(); returns: GL_NO_ERROR 
59: glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
60: glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
61: glNormal3d(-0.850651, -0.525731, 0);
62: glTexCoord2d(0.992188, 0.09375);
63: glVertex3d(-1.26412, -1.48562, 24.4911);
64: glNormal3d(-0.442863, -0.238856, 0.864188);
65: glTexCoord2d(0.863281, 0.09375);
66: glVertex3d(-2.38855, -4.58812, 22.0171);
67: glNormal3d(-0.587785, 0.425325, 0.688191);
68: glTexCoord2d(0.992188, 0.039062);
69: glVertex3d(-1.76387, -0.741022, 22.2232);
70: glEnd();
71: glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
72: glGetError(); returns: GL_NO_ERROR 
73: glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
74: glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
75: glNormal3d(1, 0, 0);
76: glTexCoord2d(0.730469, 0.257812);
77: glVertex3d(3.10864, -5.70501, 24.0788);
78: glNormal3d(0.587785, 0.425325, 0.688191);
79: glTexCoord2d(0.992188, 0.277344);
80: glVertex3d(2.9837, -5.82911, 20.78);
81: glNormal3d(-0.442863, -0.238856, 0.864188);
82: glTexCoord2d(0.863281, 0.039062);
83: glVertex3d(-2.38855, -4.58812, 22.0171);
84: glEnd();
85: glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
86: glGetError(); returns: GL_NO_ERROR 
87: glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
88: glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
89: glNormal3d(0.295242, 0, -0.955423);
90: glTexCoord2d(0.863281, 0);
91: glVertex3d(-1.63893, -4.09171, 24.4911);
92: glNormal3d(-0.850651, -0.525731, 0);
93: glTexCoord2d(0.992188, 0.09375);
94: glVertex3d(-1.26412, -1.48562, 24.4911);
95: glNormal3d(0.525731, 0.850651, 0);
96: glTexCoord2d(0.730469, 0.472656);
97: glVertex3d(3.48344, -1.48562, 24.4911);
98: glEnd();
99: glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
100: glGetError(); returns: GL_NO_ERROR
```

Comment: Sorry for being a douche but had to correct your heading double negative : not drawing nothing means it's drawing something

Comment: Yep, you are right, I corrected it

Comment: Have a look at your "OpenGL Call Stack": `27: glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` then everything between `31: glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);` and `41: glEnd();` is fed with `0`s. The second `43: glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);` til `53: glEnd();` looks much more reasonable but it renders with texture disabled. I guess, you have to debug your loop as it seems to be wrong somehow...

Comment: Yes, I will check that, also I'm receiving two GL_INVALID_OPERATION GL_INVALID_OPERATION in the gl errors, I will check on that

Comment: I fixed the 0s feed, but receiving some GL_INVALID_OPERATION but only on the first vertex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And is returning a GLuint 61964157, so seems to be working.

Nope, that's very suspicious to not actually working. While a correct implementation could come up with such a weird name, no real world implementation does that.

> OpenGL Call Stack
>
> ```
> [...]
> 21: glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
> 22: glGenTextures(1, 0x7fff59a00a08);
> 23: glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 152813080);
> ```

Firs tof all, this isn't a call stack, but just a trace of the sequence of OpenGL calls your application did.

The real error here is that you try to create the texture inside a `glBegin/glEnd` block, which is not allowed. As a result, `glGenTextures` generates just a GL error, and leaves the texture name uninitialized, which results in some random value from your stack being used as texture name.

Aprart from those errors, your code is really horrible:

1. You are calling `glewInit` inside the display function, while it should be called just once after the GL context was created.
2. You also try to re-load the texture each frame.
3. To make things worse, you never even delete the old texture, so you would be leaking the texture object (and memory) with each iteration.
4. You have some `glRotate` and `glScale` calls at the end of your display function, without drawing anything with it, and overwriting that state again in the next iteration.

And for the worst part: all of that code is completely deprecated OpenGL, which will not work with modern core profiles of OpenGL. This stuff is outfdated *for over a decade* by now, and using the fixed-function pipeline and immediate mode rendering with Begin/End and GL's matrix stack is just not the way to go in 2017.